# How to make this output backwards

Tags: java, arrays, graph, while-loop

So I have written a program that implements graphs in java and have gotten everything how i want it to work minus printing my path array in the correct order.

```
    public void printThePaths(int v) {
    for(int i = 0; i < path.length;i++){
        System.out.println("From " + v + " to " + i);
        int n = i;
        while(n != -1) {
            System.out.print(n);
            n = path[n];
        }
        System.out.println();
        //System.out.print(path[i] + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}//end
```

At this point the paths array looks like this:

```
path[] = {3,5,4,-1,4}
```

So when I run my printThePaths method it outputs like this:

```
From 4 to 0
0324
From 4 to 1
154
From 4 to 2
24
From 4 to 3
324
From 4 to 4
4
From 4 to 5
54
```

Well the paths are printing in reverse order and I'm wondering what the best approach would be to print them in the opposite direction (aka from 4 to 0 would be : 4, 3, 2 , 0). Just so everyone understands, the number inside the index is that index's parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion!

In your method, replace the `while` loop with:

```
printPath( i );
```

Then add that method:

```
void printPath( int n ) {
    if ( n != -1 ) {
        printPath( path[n] );
        System.out.print( n );
    }
}
```

Comment: oh wow recursion! Can you explain to me how you came to that?! They didn't teach us enough about recursion.. id really like to know your thought process

Comment: To print the path in reverse, you need to print everything but the first item in reverse (the recursive call), then print the first element.  And if the path is empty, there is nothing to do.